# LWJGL - Text Rendering

Tags: java, opengl, text, 2d, lwjgl

I need to render 2d text over my 2d game but none of the solutions work for me. I have used both slick and bitmap rendering. I think that part of my problem is the fact that I cant find an updated version of slick that has Unicode Fonts. Mine only has TrueType. Link me a download for slick or help me out with another type of rendering. At the moment i am using the rubbish class found here

EDIT: When I run the the demo program on lwjgl wiki it renders the fonts correctly (found here)

```
import java.awt.Font;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.lwjgl.BufferUtils;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.DisplayMode;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;
import org.newdawn.slick.TrueTypeFont;
import org.newdawn.slick.opengl.PNGDecoder;

import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;

public class Reign {

private static Player player;
public static final int WIDTH = 1280;
public static final int HEIGHT = 720;
private static Level level = new Level();
public static int levelNum = 1;

private static TrueTypeFont font;
private static int fontTexture;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // Set screen size
    Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
    Display.create();
    Display.setTitle("Reign - The Platform Game | Pre Alpha 1.0.1 (DEV 3a)");
    //Fonts??
            //This is where I load the slick font that wont work
    Font awtFont = new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 24);
    font = new TrueTypeFont(awtFont, false);
    // Player instance
    player = new Player();
    init();



    // Mainloop
    while (!Display.isCloseRequested()) {
                    //Here I try to render the slik font that wont work
                    font.drawString(100, 100, "HELLO");
        // Call main render method
        setCamera();
        // Draw the Background
        drawBG();
        // update and draw the player
        player.update();
        // Draw Platforms
        for (final Platform platform : level.getPlatforms()) {
            platform.Draw();
        }
        //Draw mobs
        for (Mob mob : level.getMobs()) {
            mob.update();
        }
        // Draw Goal
        level.getGP().Draw();
        // Update screen
        Display.update();
        // 60fps
        Display.sync(60);

        if (player.win) {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            level = new Level();
            player.win = false;
            player.reset();
            levelNum++;
        }
    }
    Display.destroy();
}

public static void init() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    fontTexture = glGenTextures();
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, fontTexture);
    final PNGDecoder decoder = new PNGDecoder(new FileInputStream(
            "res/font.png"));
    final ByteBuffer buffer = BufferUtils.createByteBuffer(4
            * decoder.getWidth() * decoder.getHeight());
    decoder.decode(buffer, decoder.getWidth() * 4, PNGDecoder.ABGR);
    buffer.flip();
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE, 0, GL_RGB, decoder.getWidth(),
            decoder.getHeight(), 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
}

// important Opengl shit
public static void setCamera() {
    glClearColor(1f, 1f, 1f, 1.0f);
    // Clear
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    // Modify projection matrix - 2d projection
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0, 1280, 0, 720, -1, 1);

    // Modify modelview matrix
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

}

private static void renderString(String string, int textureObject,
        int gridSize, float x, float y, float characterWidth,
        float characterHeight) {
    glPushAttrib(GL_TEXTURE_BIT | GL_ENABLE_BIT | GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureObject);
    // Enable linear texture filtering for smoothed results.
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    // Enable additive blending. This means that the colours will be added
    // to already existing colours in the
    // frame buffer. In practice, this makes the black parts of the texture
    // become invisible.
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE);
    // Store the current model-view matrix.
    glPushMatrix();
    // Offset all subsequent (at least up until 'glPopMatrix') vertex
    // coordinates.
    glTranslatef(x, y, 0);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    // Iterate over all the characters in the string.
    for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) {
        // Get the ASCII-code of the character by type-casting to integer.
        final int asciiCode = string.charAt(i);
        // There are 16 cells in a texture, and a texture coordinate ranges
        // from 0.0 to 1.0.
        final float cellSize = 1.0f / gridSize;
        // The cell's x-coordinate is the greatest integer smaller than
        // remainder of the ASCII-code divided by the
        // amount of cells on the x-axis, times the cell size.
        final float cellX = asciiCode % gridSize * cellSize;
        // The cell's y-coordinate is the greatest integer smaller than the
        // ASCII-code divided by the amount of
        // cells on the y-axis.
        final float cellY = asciiCode / gridSize * cellSize;
        glTexCoord2f(cellX, cellY + cellSize);
        glVertex2f(i * characterWidth / 3, y);
        glTexCoord2f(cellX + cellSize, cellY + cellSize);
        glVertex2f(i * characterWidth / 3 + characterWidth / 2, y);
        glTexCoord2f(cellX + cellSize, cellY);
        glVertex2f(i * characterWidth / 3 + characterWidth / 2, y
                + characterHeight);
        glTexCoord2f(cellX, cellY);
        glVertex2f(i * characterWidth / 3, y + characterHeight);
    }
    glEnd();
    glPopMatrix();
    glPopAttrib();
}

public static void drawBG() {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    renderString("hello", fontTexture, 16, -0.9f, 0, 0.3f, 0.225f);

    // static sky
    {
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glColor3d(0.3, 0.4, 0.6);
        glVertex2d(0, 0);
        glVertex2d(1280, 0);

        glColor3d(0.1, 0.2, 0.5);
        glVertex2d(1280, 720);
        glVertex2d(0, 720);
        glEnd();
    }
    // static ground
    {
        // mud
        {
            glBegin(GL_QUADS);
            glColor3d(0.6, 0.2, 0.1);
            glVertex2d(0, 0);
            glVertex2d(1280, 0);

            glVertex2d(1280, 32);
            glVertex2d(0, 32);
            glEnd();
        }
        // grass
        {
            glBegin(GL_QUADS);
            glColor3d(0.2, 0.75, 0.2);
            glVertex2d(0, 32);
            glVertex2d(1280, 32);

            glVertex2d(1280, 37);
            glVertex2d(0, 37);
            glEnd();
        }

        //GUI TOP
        {

                            /*
             * For a quad the coords are:
             * vertex 1 = 0, 0
             * vertex 2 = width, 0
             * vertex 3 = width, height
             * vertex 4 = 0, height
             */
            glBegin(GL_QUADS);
            glColor3d(0, 0, 0);
            glVertex2d(0, 720);
            glVertex2d(1280, 720);

            glVertex2d(1280, 640);
            glVertex2d(0, 640);
            glEnd();
        }

        //RENDER HINTS
        if (levelNum == 1) {
            drawString("Watch out for the spikes, ", 200, 700);
            drawString("they will kill you if you get too close!", 200, 685);

        }
        if (levelNum == 2) {
            drawString("Those red mobs will kill you just like spikes", 200, 700);
            drawString(" but you can win points if you jump on their heads!", 200, 685);

        }
        if (levelNum == 3) {
            drawString("The pink platforms will dissappear", 200, 700);
            drawString("after a while so watch out! ", 200, 685);
        }
        if (levelNum == 5) {
            drawString("The blue platforms are TRAMPOLINES!!", 200, 700);
        }
    }
}

public static ArrayList<Platform> getPlatforms() {
    return level.getPlatforms();
}

public static ArrayList<Mob> getMobs() {
    return level.getMobs();
}

public static void drawString(String s, int x, int y) {
      int startX = x;
      GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_POINTS);
      glColor3d(0, 1, 0);
      for (char c : s.toLowerCase().toCharArray()) {
         if (c == 'a') {
            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
               GL11.glVertex2f(x + 1, y + i);
               GL11.glVertex2f(x + 7, y + i);
            }
            for (int i = 2; i <= 6; i++) {
               GL11.glVertex2f(x + i, y + 8);
               GL11.glVertex2f(x + i, y + 4);
            }
            x += 8;
         } else if (c == 'b') {
            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
               GL11.glVertex2f(x + 1, y + i);
            }
            for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
               GL11.glVertex2f(x + i, y);
               GL11.glVertex2f(x + i, y + 4);
               GL11.glVertex2f(x + i, y + 8);
            }
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 7, y + 5);
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 7, y + 7);
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 7, y + 6);
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 7, y + 1);
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 7, y + 2);
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 7, y + 3);
            x += 8;
         } else if (c == 'c') {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
               GL11.glVertex2f(x + 1, y + i);
            }
            for (int i = 2; i <= 5; i++) {
               GL11.glVertex2f(x + i, y);
               GL11.glVertex2f(x + i, y + 8);
            }
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 6, y + 1);
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 6, y + 2);

            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 6, y + 6);
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 6, y + 7);

            x += 8;
         } else if (c == 'd') {
            for (int i = 0; i <= 8; i++) {
               GL11.glVertex2f(x + 1, y + i);
            }
            for (int i = 2; i <= 5; i++) {
               GL11.glVertex2f(x + i, y);
               GL11.glVertex2f(x + i, y + 8);
            }
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 6, y + 1);
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 6, y + 2);
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 6, y + 3);
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 6, y + 4);
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 6, y + 5);
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 6, y + 6);
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 6, y + 7);

            x += 8;
         } else if (c == 'e') {
            for (int i = 0; i <= 8; i++) {
               GL11.glVertex2f(x + 1, y + i);
            }
            for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
               GL11.glVertex2f(x + i, y + 0);
               GL11.glVertex2f(x + i, y + 8);
            }
            for (int i = 2; i <= 5; i++) {
               GL11.glVertex2f(x + i, y + 4);
            }
            x += 8;
         } else if (c == 'f') {
            for (int i = 0; i <= 8; i++) {
               GL11.glVertex2f(x + 1, y + i);
            }
            for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
               GL11.glVertex2f(x + i, y + 8);
            }
            for (int i = 2; i <= 5; i++) {
               GL11.glVertex2f(x + i, y + 4);
            }
            x += 8;
         } else if (c == 'g') {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
               GL11.glVertex2f(x + 1, y + i);
            }
            for (int i = 2; i <= 5; i++) {
               GL11.glVertex2f(x + i, y);
               GL11.glVertex2f(x + i, y + 8);
            }
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 6, y + 1);
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 6, y + 2);
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 6, y + 3);
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 5, y + 3);
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 7, y + 3);

            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 6, y + 6);
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 6, y + 7);

            x += 8;
         } else if (c == 'h') {
            for (int i = 0; i <= 8; i++) {
               GL11.glVertex2f(x + 1, y + i);
               GL11.glVertex2f(x + 7, y + i);
            }
            for (int i = 2; i <= 6; i++) {
               GL11.glVertex2f(x + i, y + 4);
            }
            x += 8;
         } else if (c == 'i') {
            for (int i = 0; i <= 8; i++) {
               GL11.glVertex2f(x + 3, y + i);
            }
            for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
               GL11.glVertex2f(x + i, y + 0);
               GL11.glVertex2f(x + i, y + 8);
            }
            x += 7;
         } else if (c == 'j') {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
               GL11.glVertex2f(x + 6, y + i);
            }
            for (int i = 2; i <= 5; i++) {
               GL11.glVertex2f(x + i, y + 0);
            }
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 1, y + 3);
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 1, y + 2);
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 1, y + 1);
            x += 8;
         } else if (c == 'k') {
            for (int i = 0; i <= 8; i++) {
               GL11.glVertex2f(x + 1, y + i);
            }
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 6, y + 8);
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 5, y + 7);
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 4, y + 6);
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 3, y + 5);
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 2, y + 4);
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 2, y + 3);
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 3, y + 4);
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 4, y + 3);
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 5, y + 2);
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 6, y + 1);
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 7, y);
            x += 8;
         } else if (c == 'l') {
            for (int i = 0; i <= 8; i++) {
               GL11.glVertex2f(x + 1, y + i);
            }
            for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
               GL11.glVertex2f(x + i, y);
            }
            x += 7;
         } else if (c == 'm') {
            for (int i = 0; i <= 8; i++) {
               GL11.glVertex2f(x + 1, y + i);
               GL11.glVertex2f(x + 7, y + i);
            }
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 3, y + 6);
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 2, y + 7);
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 4, y + 5);

            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 5, y + 6);
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 6, y + 7);
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 4, y + 5);
            x += 8;
         } else if (c == 'n') {
            for (int i = 0; i <= 8; i++) {
               GL11.glVertex2f(x + 1, y + i);
               GL11.glVertex2f(x + 7, y + i);
            }
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 2, y + 7);
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 2, y + 6);
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 3, y + 5);
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 4, y + 4);
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 5, y + 3);
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 6, y + 2);
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 6, y + 1);
            x += 8;
         } else if (c == 'o' || c == '0') {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
               GL11.glVertex2f(x + 1, y + i);
               GL11.glVertex2f(x + 7, y + i);
            }
            for (int i = 2; i <= 6; i++) {
               GL11.glVertex2f(x + i, y + 8);
               GL11.glVertex2f(x + i, y + 0);
            }
            x += 8;
         } else if (c == 'p') {
            for (int i = 0; i <= 8; i++) {
               GL11.glVertex2f(x + 1, y + i);
            }
            for (int i = 2; i <= 5; i++) {
               GL11.glVertex2f(x + i, y + 8);
               GL11.glVertex2f(x + i, y + 4);
            }
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 6, y + 7);
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 6, y + 5);
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 6, y + 6);
            x += 8;
         } else if (c == 'q') {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
               GL11.glVertex2f(x + 1, y + i);
               if (i != 1)
                  GL11.glVertex2f(x + 7, y + i);
            }
            for (int i = 2; i <= 6; i++) {
               GL11.glVertex2f(x + i, y + 8);
               if (i != 6)
                  GL11.glVertex2f(x + i, y + 0);
            }
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 4, y + 3);
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 5, y + 2);
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 6, y + 1);
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 7, y);
            x += 8;
         } else if (c == 'r') {
            for (int i = 0; i <= 8; i++) {
               GL11.glVertex2f(x + 1, y + i);
            }
            for (int i = 2; i <= 5; i++) {
               GL11.glVertex2f(x + i, y + 8);
               GL11.glVertex2f(x + i, y + 4);
            }
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 6, y + 7);
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 6, y + 5);
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 6, y + 6);

            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 4, y + 3);
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 5, y + 2);
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 6, y + 1);
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 7, y);
            x += 8;
         } else if (c == 's') {
            for (int i = 2; i <= 7; i++) {
               GL11.glVertex2f(x + i, y + 8);
            }
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 1, y + 7);
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 1, y + 6);
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 1, y + 5);
            for (int i = 2; i <= 6; i++) {
               GL11.glVertex2f(x + i, y + 4);
               GL11.glVertex2f(x + i, y);
            }
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 7, y + 3);
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 7, y + 2);
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 7, y + 1);
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 1, y + 1);
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 1, y + 2);
            x += 8;
         } else if (c == 't') {
            for (int i = 0; i <= 8; i++) {
               GL11.glVertex2f(x + 4, y + i);
            }
            for (int i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
               GL11.glVertex2f(x + i, y + 8);
            }
            x += 7;
         } else if (c == 'u') {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
               GL11.glVertex2f(x + 1, y + i);
               GL11.glVertex2f(x + 7, y + i);
            }
            for (int i = 2; i <= 6; i++) {
               GL11.glVertex2f(x + i, y + 0);
            }
            x += 8;
         } else if (c == 'v') {
            for (int i = 2; i <= 8; i++) {
               GL11.glVertex2f(x + 1, y + i);
               GL11.glVertex2f(x + 6, y + i);
            }
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 2, y + 1);
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 5, y + 1);
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 3, y);
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 4, y);
            x += 7;
         } else if (c == 'w') {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
               GL11.glVertex2f(x + 1, y + i);
               GL11.glVertex2f(x + 7, y + i);
            }
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 2, y);
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 3, y);
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 5, y);
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 6, y);
            for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
               GL11.glVertex2f(x + 4, y + i);
            }
            x += 8;
         } else if (c == 'x') {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 7; i++)
               GL11.glVertex2f(x + i, y + i);
            for (int i = 7; i >= 1; i--)
               GL11.glVertex2f(x + i, y + 8 - i);
            x += 8;
         } else if (c == 'y') {
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 4, y);
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 4, y + 1);
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 4, y + 2);
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 4, y + 3);
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 4, y + 4);

            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 3, y + 5);
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 2, y + 6);
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 1, y + 7);
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 1, y + 8);

            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 5, y + 5);
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 6, y + 6);
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 7, y + 7);
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 7, y + 8);
            x += 8;
         } else if (c == 'z') {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
               GL11.glVertex2f(x + i, y);
               GL11.glVertex2f(x + i, y + 8);
               GL11.glVertex2f(x + i, y + i);
            }
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 6, y + 7);
            x += 8;
         } else if (c == '1') {
            for (int i = 2; i <= 6; i++) {
               GL11.glVertex2f(x + i, y);
            }
            for (int i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
               GL11.glVertex2f(x + 4, y + i);
            }
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 3, y + 7);
            x += 8;
         } else if (c == '2') {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
               GL11.glVertex2f(x + i, y);
            }
            for (int i = 2; i <= 5; i++) {
               GL11.glVertex2f(x + i, y + 8);
            }
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 1, y + 7);
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 1, y + 6);

            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 6, y + 7);
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 6, y + 6);
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 6, y + 5);
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 5, y + 4);
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 4, y + 3);
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 3, y + 2);
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 2, y + 1);
            x += 8;
         } else if (c == '3') {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
               GL11.glVertex2f(x + i, y + 8);
               GL11.glVertex2f(x + i, y);
            }
            for (int i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
               GL11.glVertex2f(x + 6, y + i);
            }
            for (int i = 2; i <= 5; i++) {
               GL11.glVertex2f(x + i, y + 4);
            }
            x += 8;
         } else if (c == '4') {
            for (int i = 2; i <= 8; i++) {
               GL11.glVertex2f(x + 1, y + i);
            }
            for (int i = 2; i <= 7; i++) {
               GL11.glVertex2f(x + i, y + 1);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
               GL11.glVertex2f(x + 4, y + i);
            }
            x += 8;
         } else if (c == '5') {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
               GL11.glVertex2f(x + i, y + 8);
            }
            for (int i = 4; i <= 7; i++) {
               GL11.glVertex2f(x + 1, y + i);
            }
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 1, y + 1);
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 2, y);
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 3, y);
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 4, y);
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 5, y);
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 6, y);

            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 7, y + 1);
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 7, y + 2);
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 7, y + 3);

            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 6, y + 4);
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 5, y + 4);
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 4, y + 4);
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 3, y + 4);
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 2, y + 4);
            x += 8;
         } else if (c == '6') {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
               GL11.glVertex2f(x + 1, y + i);
            }
            for (int i = 2; i <= 6; i++) {
               GL11.glVertex2f(x + i, y);
            }
            for (int i = 2; i <= 5; i++) {
               GL11.glVertex2f(x + i, y + 4);
               GL11.glVertex2f(x + i, y + 8);
            }
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 7, y + 1);
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 7, y + 2);
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 7, y + 3);
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 6, y + 4);
            x += 8;
         } else if (c == '7') {
            for (int i = 0; i <= 7; i++)
               GL11.glVertex2f(x + i, y + 8);
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 7, y + 7);
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 7, y + 6);

            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 6, y + 5);
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 5, y + 4);
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 4, y + 3);
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 3, y + 2);
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 2, y + 1);
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 1, y);
            x += 8;
         } else if (c == '8') {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
               GL11.glVertex2f(x + 1, y + i);
               GL11.glVertex2f(x + 7, y + i);
            }
            for (int i = 2; i <= 6; i++) {
               GL11.glVertex2f(x + i, y + 8);
               GL11.glVertex2f(x + i, y + 0);
            }
            for (int i = 2; i <= 6; i++) {
               GL11.glVertex2f(x + i, y + 4);
            }
            x += 8;
         } else if (c == '9') {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
               GL11.glVertex2f(x + 7, y + i);
            }
            for (int i = 5; i <= 7; i++) {
               GL11.glVertex2f(x + 1, y + i);
            }
            for (int i = 2; i <= 6; i++) {
               GL11.glVertex2f(x + i, y + 8);
               GL11.glVertex2f(x + i, y + 0);
            }
            for (int i = 2; i <= 6; i++) {
               GL11.glVertex2f(x + i, y + 4);
            }
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 1, y + 0);
            x += 8;
         } else if (c == '.') {
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 1, y);
            x += 2;
         } else if (c == ',') {
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 1, y);
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + 1, y + 1);
            x += 2;
         } else if (c == '\n') {
            y -= 10;
            x = startX;
         } else if (c == ' ') {
            x += 8;
         }
      }
      GL11.glEnd();
   }

}
```

Comment: Can you include the code in the post?

Comment: I did but its just the main class. it has where i want to render the slick font plus the drawing method!

Comment: Unfortunately, ".. [no] Unicode Fonts. Mine only has TrueType .." is a verifiable nonsense statement. What advantage are you hoping to achieve using "Unicode over Truetype"?

Comment: For god sake, why on earth you are using deprecated OpenGL API...And to your problem,there are tons of text rendering open source libs out there written in C/C++ which can be ported to Java without any problem.